# Guitar support for Yamaha SLG200NW

Tags: guitar, practice

I bought a silent guitar [Yamaha SLG200NW](https://ca.yamaha.com/en/products/musical_instruments/guitars_basses/silent_guitar/slg200_series/index.html) around 6 months ago. I like it very much. However, there is one thing that doesn't allow me to fully enjoy practising on that guitar. I cannot find a proper position. In classical position (on the left leg) the upper part of the guitar's frame pushes against my sternum bone making it hurt. In the position when the guitar is on the right leg, I have to bend too much even though I use a footstool in the most upper position, so now I have pain in my back. I also tried a strap, it didn't go very well eighter.

I tried to find a guitar support, but couldn't due to the very thin body frame of the guitar. The width of the bottom frame is 28mm, and the width of the horn is 21mm.

Does anybody use any guitar support while playing this guitar?

Answer (score 2):

1. Try playing with strap while standing. Might be more comfortable and make you slouch less than sitting position.
2. In addition to the footstool you can put guitar "cushion" or "pillow" support on your leg. They don't attach to the guitar, so should work with an instrument of any thickness.
3. It's rare, but some musicians use a guitar supports which stand on the ground, thus don't require you to support the instrument by yourself. I found this example link: https://vikingguitarstands.com/ but I have no knowledge of this specific company and their products.
4. Electric guitar support. I'm aware of this product: https://guitarscientist.com/performaxe/ but again, I have never used it, and I don't know if it would work with the frame of Yamaha Silent.